# How to know where a .f90 file installed?

Tags: python, linux, fortran

I installed a Linux software with compile, make install. Then I can't find a file called aaa.f90, the aaa.f90 is called by bbb.py, those two files are in my installation directory. How can I know where did it install from Makefile? I tried 'which aaa.f90', it's not work.

I tried to read Makefile.am, Makefile.in, but it's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`which` searches the path for executables.  Why not just use find to look for it from the command line?
Example:

```
find / -name aaa.f90 -print
```

It's possible you might need sudo to find a given file this way, but it seems unlikely in this case.

Comment: Two many files, a lot of directories I don't have permission to access. Anyway to find where did it install by searching the Makefile?

Comment: Well, without seeing the makefile, I can't guess.  If you redirect the output of the make process to a file, and search through it, you should be able to find it.

Comment: Looks like this is the only method. I don't like the automake software which make the Makefile so complicate.

Comment: If you are on bash, you can use `find / -name aaa.f90 -print 2> /dev/null` which will hide all the error messages so that you only see real hits.